# How to write multivariate logarithmic regression with Python and sklearn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression

I wrote a code for multivariate polynomial regression, I used polynomial features and transformation function from sklearn. Is it possible to make multivariate logarithmic regression?
Does sklearn have some kind of logarithmic transformation, like it has for polynomial features?
How can I write multivariate logarithmic regression in python?

This is my code for multivariate polynomial features:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import math
import xlrd
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures


#Reading data from excel

data = pd.read_excel("DataSet.xls").round(2)
data_size = data.shape[0]
#print("Number of data:",data_size,"\n",data.head())

def polynomial_prediction_of_future_strength(input_data, cement, blast_fur_slug,fly_ash,
                                              water, superpl, coarse_aggr, fine_aggr, days):

    variables = prediction_accuracy(input_data)[2]
    results = prediction_accuracy(input_data)[3]
    n = results.shape[0]
    results = results.values.reshape(n,1) #reshaping the values so that variables and results have the same shape

    #transforming the data into polynomial function
    Poly_Regression = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)
    poly_variables = Poly_Regression.fit_transform(variables)

    #accuracy of prediction(splitting the dataset on train and test)
    poly_var_train, poly_var_test, res_train, res_test = train_test_split(poly_variables, results, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 4)

    input_values = [cement, blast_fur_slug, fly_ash, water, superpl, coarse_aggr, fine_aggr, days]
    input_values = Poly_Regression.transform([input_values]) #transforming the data for prediction in polynomial function

    regression = linear_model.LinearRegression() #making the linear model
    model = regression.fit(poly_var_train, res_train) #fitting polynomial data to the model

    predicted_strength = regression.predict(input_values) #strength prediction
    predicted_strength = round(predicted_strength[0,0], 2)

    score = model.score(poly_var_test, res_test) #accuracy prediction
    score = round(score*100, 2)

    accuracy_info = "Accuracy of concrete class prediction: " + str(score) + " %\n"
    prediction_info = "Prediction of future concrete class after "+ str(days)+" days: "+ str(predicted_strength) 

    info = "\n" + accuracy_info + prediction_info

    return info

#print(polynomial_prediction_of_future_strength(data, 214.9 , 53.8, 121.9, 155.6, 9.6, 1014.3, 780.6, 7))
```

Comment: [Here is a discussion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/190107/curve-fit-with-logarithmic-regression-in-python) on stats.stackexchange regarding fitting with logarithmic curves, some of the answers might be helpful

Comment: I know how to make logarithmic regression with one parameter using numpy, But I do not know how to make it with multiple variables/parameters.

Comment: I have tried to make a logarithm of my pandas values but it does not work

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fit with the logarithms of your features, one option is the Box-Cox Transform then OLS, which you can apply in sklearn using the PowerTransformer. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PowerTransformer.html#sklearn.preprocessing.PowerTransformer

Comment: I want to make logarithmic regression, I know how to make linear regression (linear function) and I know how to make polynomial regression (polynomial function). Now I want to find a way to make logarithmic regression

Comment: What do you mean by logarithmic regression? Polynomial regression is just linear regression on polynomial transformations of the features. If you want the same thing but with logarithmic transformations, then the Box-Cox transformation does this for you.

Comment: Thanks, Im trying to do that in my code, but i do not manage to do it, i do not understand the documentation. It would be nice if you could change the code that i posted, just to add the things that you think, because im trying to do that for the last 45 min, and I do not manage to do it

Comment: If you can write me an example code, i would be very thankful. I have a code that i posted with `from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures` , but I do not know how to change that to PowerTransformer, Box-Cox.